# Why do I get an empty string when getting the innertext from a p-tag with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to make a web-api for this site: http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html

The description of the image is in a "p"-tag. So with my C# code I tried getting everything in the tag and parse it as a string. My code looks like this:

```
Description = item.SelectSingleNode("p").InnerText()
```

This just returns a string with value "". It isn't null, but just empty. 
Why doesn't it show the text in the tags?

If I do:

```
Description = item.SelectSingleNode("p").NextSibling.NextSibling.Innertext
```

then it does show the first word of the paragraph: "Explanation:", which is between "b"-tags.

Here is the complete  HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Astronomy Picture of the Day
</title>
<!-- gsfc meta tags -->
<meta name="orgcode" content="661">
<meta name="rno" content="phillip.a.newman">
<meta name="content-owner" content="Jerry.T.Bonnell.1">
<meta name="webmaster" content="Stephen.F.Fantasia.1">
<meta name="description" content="A different astronomy and space science
related image is featured each day, along with a brief explanation.">
<!-- -->
<meta name="keywords" content="full moon, lunar phase">
<script id="_fed_an_js_tag" type="text/javascript"
src="js/federated-analytics.all.min.js?agency=NASA"></script>

</head>
<body BGCOLOR="#F4F4FF" text="#000000" link="#0000FF" vlink="#7F0F9F"
alink="#FF0000">

<center>
<h1> Astronomy Picture of the Day </h1>
<p>

<a href="archivepix.html">Discover the cosmos!</a>
Each day a different image or photograph of our fascinating universe is
featured, along with a brief explanation written by a professional astronomer.
<p>

2015 January 10
<br>

<a href="image/1501/_MG_4115sTafreshi.jpg">
<IMG SRC="image/1501/_MG_4115sTafreshi1024.jpg"
alt="See Explanation.  Clicking on the picture will download
 the highest resolution version available."></a>

</center>

<center>
<b> The Windmill's Moon </b> <br>

<b> Image Credit &
<a href="lib/about_apod.html#srapply">Copyright</a>: </b>

<a href="http://www.twanight.org/tafreshi">Babak Tafreshi</a>
(<a href="http://www.twanight.org/">TWAN</a>)

</center> 

<p> 

<b> Explanation: </b>

Seen from the
<a href="http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/IOTD/view.php?id=81421">Canary
Island</a>
of
<a href="http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/NaturalHazards/
view.php?id=77372">Fuerteventura</a>, this bright
Full Moon rose at sunset.

Reaching its full phase
<a href="http://earthsky.org/tonight/
january-full-moon-mimics-path-of-july-sun">on the night</a>
of January 4/5, it was
the first Full Moon of the new year and the first to follow
December's solstice.

Of course, in North America the first Full Moon of January
has been known as
<a href="ap120120.html">the Wolf's Moon</a>.

But this Full Moon, posed in the twilight above an island of strong
winds and traditional windmills,
suggests another name.

<a href="http://www.dreamview.net/dv/new/photos.asp?ID=104104">The
telephoto image</a>, taken at a distance from the foreground
windmill, creates the
<a href="http://home.hiwaay.net/~krcool/Astro/moon/moonwords/
moonpoems.htm">dramatic</a> comparison in
<a href="ap080801.html">apparent</a> size for windmill and Full Moon.

<p><center>

<b> Tomorrow's picture: </b>Cataclysmic Dawn

<p> <hr>
<a href="ap150109.html">&lt;</a>
| <a href="archivepix.html">Archive</a>
| <a href="lib/apsubmit2015.html">Submissions</a>
| <a href="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/apod/apod_search">Search</a>
| <a href="calendar/allyears.html">Calendar</a>
| <a href="/apod.rss">RSS</a>
| <a href="lib/edlinks.html">Education</a>
| <a href="lib/about_apod.html">About APOD</a>
| <a href=
"http://asterisk.apod.com/discuss_apod.php?date=150110">Discuss</a>
| <a href="ap150111.html">&gt;</a>

<hr><p>
<b> Authors & editors: </b>
<a href="http://www.phy.mtu.edu/faculty/Nemiroff.html">Robert Nemiroff</a>
(<a href="http://www.phy.mtu.edu/">MTU</a>) &
<a href="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/htmltest/jbonnell/www/bonnell.html"
>Jerry Bonnell</a> (<a href="http://www.astro.umd.edu/">UMCP</a>)<br>
<b>NASA Official: </b> Phillip Newman
<a href="lib/about_apod.html#srapply">Specific rights apply</a>.<br>
<a href="http://www.nasa.gov/about/highlights/HP_Privacy.html">NASA Web
Privacy Policy and Important Notices</a><br>
<b>A service of:</b>
<a href="http://astrophysics.gsfc.nasa.gov/">ASD</a> at
<a href="http://www.nasa.gov/">NASA</a> /
<a href="http://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/">GSFC</a>
<br><b>&</b> <a href="http://www.mtu.edu/">Michigan Tech. U.</a><br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For this question to be answerable you need to post small HTML sample that reproduces the problem... Also if you just look at HTML yourself and see if there is any content in first "P" tag you may get answer yourself...

Comment: Because `InnerText` is not `InnerHtml`, there's only HTML in that paragraph.

Comment: `item` is everything between the `body`tags.
And if I do it with InnerHTML, I get the same result.

Comment: When I open [your site](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html) with chrome, inspect the element and copy the xpath, it returns `/html/body/center[2]/b[1]`. There is no **p**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because there is no `</p>` tag. So it just returns nothing.

I fixed it with this code:

```
var description = item.SelectSingleNode("p").NextSibling.NextSibling;
string a = string.Empty;
while (description != item.SelectNodes("p")[1])
{
    a += description.InnerText + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    description = description.NextSibling;
}
apod.Description = a;
```